# Getting error of doorkeeper after installation of rails admin :doorkeeper_authorize! has not been defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rails-admin

I am getting error before my call back `process_action` callback.

```
:doorkeeper_authorize! has not been defined
```

I started get this error after my installation of `rails admin`.

```
class Api::V1::User::UsersController < Api::ApiApplicationController
  skip_before_action :doorkeeper_authorize!, only: %i[create]

  def create
    user = User.new(user_params)
  end
end
```

Comment: You may need to write error in details. Always use code syntax for showing errors and codes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I got the Solution of this problem so i put the solution in Answer Section as well.

Answer (score 0):

I just Added **before_action :doorkeeper_authorize!** this in api_application_controller.rb      So error fixed successfully.